# What does href="javascript:se(param1, param2, param ...) mean?

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering what this is doing in an href?

`javascript:se('156875566',n[0],i[0],p[0],d[0])`

The site's code is a mess and I can't find a function called "se".

It's a very general question but I've never seen this notation before:
`javascript:<function>`

Here's the site if you really want to see it: http://devonrex.rescueme.org/California

EDIT: My confusion is with the `javascript:<function>` notation but that's been answered.  Thank you guys :)

Comment: How you expect us to interpret your site's code when you didn't show it to us?  There's a function `se` somewhere... or maybe there isn't who knows.  Remember that JavaScript is very dynamic, and that this function may not be explicitly defined with `function se()`

Comment: I'm not asking for you to debug or solve anything.  I should have been clearer in my question, my bad.

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood... I thought that when you mentioned the `se()` function, you knew that the JavaScript protocol handler was calling that function.  The answers below are correct.

Comment: No worries.  My original question was ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

It's calling the function `se` on click of the link.

From your [link](http://devonrex.rescueme.org/California) `se` is a function defined in this line:

```
function se(x, y, z, x2, y2) {
    JSVoktosend = "";
    // ...
}
```

And `n`, `i`, `p`, `d` are global variables. You can see their values by typing their names on your console window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a global function. The same for n[0], i[0], p[0], d[0]: global variables. The best way to see what is doing it open the developer tools and type "se" on the console, it will returns the code (at least in Chrome). Use the same for n , i , p and d . ex:

```
 se; // it will returns something like : function(a ,b ,c ,d ,e ){  .... }
```

Or post the site's URL :D

Comment: "javascript" Isn´t a global object, the notation is for the anchors(if you call in a button dont need the "javascript:"). "se" is a global function because is called on the href and if it doesnt throw an error is because is declared on some script tag or in a external javascript file. the same for "n , i , p , d".